# Insert data to new column based on conditions given in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the dictionary specifying the value the row should take if the conditions are met

```
dict_map = {
    "Yes" : {'Sex':'F', 'Pregnant': 'Y'},
    "No" : {'Sex':'F', 'Pregnant': 'N'},
    "N/A" : {'Sex': 'M'},
    }
```

The dataframe and list

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB04', 'AB05','AB06'],
    'Sex': ["F","M","M",np.nan,"F","F"],
    'Pregnant': ['Y', 'N',np.nan, 'Y', '', 'N']
    
 }
 )

 cols_of_interest = ["Sex","Pregnant"]
```

The final dataframe should look like below with Status being the new column. How can this be done without using the merge functionality to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create the dataframe then `merge`

```
out = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(dict_map).T.reset_index(),how='left')
Out[139]: 
     ID  Sex Pregnant index
0  AB01    F        Y   Yes
1  AB02    M        N   NaN
2  AB03    M      NaN   N/A
3  AB04  NaN        Y   NaN
4  AB05    F            NaN
5  AB06    F        N    No
```

Comment: For row 1, it should be "N/A" since Sex is M and is there any other this can be done without using merge

Comment: The dictionary can be restructured if needed

Comment: is there any way this can be done without using merge functionality @BENY ?

Comment: @Fazli you may want to try map or join then

Comment: I've tried to use map but the way the dictionary is structured, it isn't working. If you have the time, could you show me how its done?