# Fill new column by following conditions listed in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the dictionary specifying the value the row should take if the conditions are met. The dictionary can be restructured if needed (or reshape it if you prefer while preserving the information in it)

```
dict_map = {
"Yes" : {'Sex':'F', 'Pregnant': 'Y'},
"No" : {'Sex':'F', 'Pregnant': 'N'},
"N/A" : {'Sex': 'M'},
}
```

And the dataframe and list

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB04', 'AB05','AB06'],
    'Sex': ["F","M","M",np.nan,"F","F"],
    'Pregnant': ['Y', 'N',np.nan, 'Y', '', 'N']
    
 }
 )

 cols_of_interest = ["Sex","Pregnant"]
```

How do I achieve the following result?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663391/insert-data-to-new-column-based-on-conditions-given-in-dictionary

Comment: It doesn't work properly, can you give this a try @DaniMesejo

Comment: What is the error, please?

Comment: @Corralien using the merge like its said in the link, For row 1, it should be "N/A" since Sex is M and but we get the result as NaN

Comment: @Corralien can you think of a solution? (If you have the time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform your `dict_map` into a `Series` of query string usable by `query` method:

```
sr = pd.Series({k1: ' & '.join([f"{k2} == '{v}'" for k2, v in d.items()])
                    for k1, d in dict_map.items()})

for v, q in sr.iteritems():
    df.loc[df.query(q).index, 'Status'] = v
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     ID  Sex Pregnant Status
0  AB01    F        Y    Yes
1  AB02    M        N    N/A
2  AB03    M      NaN    N/A
3  AB04  NaN        Y    NaN
4  AB05    F             NaN
5  AB06    F        N     No

>>> sr
Yes    Sex == 'F' & Pregnant == 'Y'
No     Sex == 'F' & Pregnant == 'N'
N/A                      Sex == 'M'
Name: Status, dtype: object
```

**Update**

> I have scenario in which the dictionary is like {'Yes': {'Sex': ('F', 'Female')},  'No': {'Sex': 'M', 'Pregnant': 'N\A'}} how do I convert this into a series like above format? In english, Yes if sex is F or Female and No if sex is M and pregnant is N\A

Use `isin` when the value is a tuple:

```
dict_map2 = {'Yes': {'Sex': ('F', 'Female')},
             'No': {'Sex': 'M', 'Pregnant': 'N\A'}}

sr = pd.Series({k1: ' & '.join((f"{k2} == '{v}'" if isinstance(v, str) 
                                    else f"{k2}.isin({v})")
                                    for k2, v in d.items())
                                    for k1, d in dict_map2.items()})
print(sr)

# Output:
Yes         Sex.isin(('F', 'Female'))
No     Sex == 'M' & Pregnant == 'N\A'
dtype: object
```

The loop still the same.

Comment: There is an invalid syntax error @Corralien

Comment: I have scenario in which the dictionary is like `{'Yes': {'Sex': ('F', 'Female')},
 'No': {'Sex': 'M', 'Pregnant': 'N\A'}}` how do I convert this into a series like above format? In english, Yes if sex is F or Female and No if sex is M and pregnant is N\A

Comment: The loop to create new column and fill is not working @Corralien

Comment: What is the error message? I changed some values (F->Female, np.nan->N\A) and it worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238500/discussion-between-fazli-and-corralien).

Comment: I get this error "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

Comment: Are you sure you have `('F', 'Female')` and not `['F', 'Female']`?

Comment: I can use either, I tried it using [] as well. It still gives me the error

Comment: What if the dictionary is in this format `dict_map2 = {'Yes': {('F', 'Female'):'Sex' },
             'No': {'M': 'Sex', 'N\A': 'Pregnant'}}` can the error be mitigated?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB04', 'AB05','AB06'],
    'Sex': ["F","M","M",np.nan,"F","F"],
    'Pregnant': ['Y', 'N',np.nan, 'Y', '', 'N'] })

dict_map = {
"Yes" : {'Sex':'F', 'Pregnant': 'Y'},
"No" : {'Sex':'F', 'Pregnant': 'N'},
"N/A" : {'Sex': 'M'},
}




for key,val in dict_map.items():
    latestId = df.ID.iloc[-1]
    newID = latestId[:2] +  str(int(latestId[2:] )+1).zfill(2) #construct newID
    
    
    df = df.append({'ID':newID, 
                    'Sex':val.get('Sex'), 
                    'Pregnant':val.get('Pregnant')},ignore_index=True)
```