# Convert nested dictionary into series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, series

I have the dictionary

```
dict_map = {
   "Yes" : {'Sex':'F', 'Pregnant': 'Y'},
   "No" : {'Sex':'F', 'Pregnant': 'N'},
   "N/A" : {'Sex': 'M'},
  }
```

and I have the code to convert it to series, but it gives me syntax error. I'm a python newbie, can you identify what needs to changed to make the code work?

```
sr = pd.Series({k1: ' & '.join([f"{k2} == '{v}'" for k2, v in d.items(
                for k1, d in dict_map.items()})
```

The resulting series should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `[` and add `))` after first `items(`:

```
sr = pd.Series({k1: ' & '.join(f"{k2} == '{v}'" for k2, v in d.items()) for k1, d in dict_map.items()})
print (sr)
Yes    Sex == 'F' & Pregnant == 'Y'
No     Sex == 'F' & Pregnant == 'N'
N/A                      Sex == 'M'
dtype: object
```

Solution with `[]` for list comprehension is posible, but not necessary:

```
sr = pd.Series({k1: ' & '.join([f"{k2} == '{v}'" for k2, v in d.items()]) for k1, d in dict_map.items()})
print (sr)
Yes    Sex == 'F' & Pregnant == 'Y'
No     Sex == 'F' & Pregnant == 'N'
N/A                      Sex == 'M'
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is a typo and it's fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69672695/15239951)

Comment: @Corralien - Sure, not necessary `[]`